# D3: Lag update on force layout links when dataset changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

The "data 15000" button changes the dataset to another one that has the same nodes, but more linkages between nodes. However, the user has to click twice in order to fully display the updated force layout.

Why is this line of code 1-click late?

```
link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return scale(d.value); });
```

How do I solve this problem? Thank you!

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ppgg2coe/4/)

The problem, basically:

[image]

Comment: please check your `JSFiddle`

Comment: @core114 updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add selection to tick function:

```
function ticked() {
    var link = linkg.selectAll("line")
    var fnode = fnodeg.selectAll("circle")
    ... update attributes for link(line) and fnode(circle).
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3aoa96qw/)

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I rly appreciate your help so much. Thank you for your time to look at my code